# PostgreSQL count occurrences into json key/value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.4

Given an array of text elements I'd like to calculate the number of occurrences and return them as a son object with a textual key and an integer value.
(PostgreSQL 9.4)

**Case 1 - without reference set**

```
SELECT ARRAY['3G','2G','2G','3G','3G','3G','3G','4G']
```

should be transformed to

```
SELECT '{"2G": 2, "3G": 5, "4G": 1}'::jsonb
```

---

**Case 2 - using a reference set**

given a set of possible entries `ARRAY['2G','3G','4G']`, the returned json should also contain elements with a zero count.

```
SELECT ARRAY['3G','2G','2G','3G','3G','3G','3G']
```

should transform to

```
SELECT '{"2G": 2, "3G": 5, "4G": 0}'::jsonb
```

---

I got quite close on case 1 and 2 by using

```
-- case 1
SELECT json_object( array_agg(r.a)::text[],array_agg(r.num)::text[] ) 
FROM (
  SELECT a, count(a) as num 
  FROM unnest( ARRAY['3G','2G','2G','3G','3G','3G','3G','4G'] ) a
  GROUP BY a ORDER BY a
) r;

--case 2
SELECT json_object( array_agg(r.ref)::text[],array_agg(r.num)::text[] ) 
FROM (
  SELECT ref, count(a) as num 
  FROM unnest( ARRAY['2G','3G','4G'] ) ref
  LEFT JOIN unnest( ARRAY['3G','2G','2G','3G','3G','3G','3G'] ) a ON (ref = a)
  GROUP BY ref ORDER BY ref
) r;
```

but, the result returns a textual value, eg:

```
SELECT '{"2G" : "2", "3G" : "5", "4G" : "0"}'::json   -- case 2
```

---

Appreciate your help and feedback!

Comment: You didn't include `4G` in `ARRAY['3G','2G','2G','3G','3G','3G','3G']`.

Comment: On purpose to demonstrate the reference case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case you can use aggregate [**`json_object_agg()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function, query will be simplier:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(r.ref,r.num) result
FROM (
  SELECT
    ref,
    count(a) AS num
  FROM unnest(ARRAY ['2G', '3G', '4G']) ref
    LEFT JOIN unnest(ARRAY ['3G', '2G', '2G', '3G', '3G', '3G', '3G']) a ON (ref = a)
  GROUP BY ref
  ORDER BY ref
) r;
```

Result is:

```
              result              
----------------------------------
 { "2G" : 2, "3G" : 5, "4G" : 0 }
(1 row)
```

Comment: I was only checking the json functions documentation on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html and didn't find `json_object_agg`there.
Many thanks, @Dmitry!